# .net core problem occured in development environment?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I try to put my .net core project on CentOS7 64bit development environment. Input cmd like this:

> dotnet TM-Log-SS-System.dll

Error occured like this:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'myfirstproject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I googled but find almost none answer on this problem.
help me

Comment: Its expected you can't run a dll it has to be an executable, dll just have code that you can invoke from other projects.

Comment: What type of project did you create? Web, console app etc? As above comment days, if it's not an executable with a program.cs class then it can't run

Comment: To run a program it must have `static void` method called `Main`, error indicates that library you are trying to run does not have such method.